# About the vector space C[Sd]

Tags: representation-theory

[image]

could you please explain what is the vector space C[Sd]? Thanx.

Comment: It is the group algebra of the symmetric group $S_d$.

Answer (score 2):

The vector space $\mathbb C[S_d]$ is more than a vector space. It is an **algebra**.

It is part of a more general construction. Let $G$ be *any* finite group, and define $\mathbb C[G]$ to be the vector space with basis $\{e_g \}_{g \in G}$. That is, you have one basis element for each element of the group. It is common to write $e_{id}$ as $1$.

The multiplication in this algebra is defined by $e_{g}e_h=e_{gh}$, and extended by linearity.

There is a natural action of $G$ on $\mathbb C[G]$, and this is exactly the **regular representation** of $G$.

Comment: Ok. got it thank you :)